# What is the easiest and most efficient way to display flattened fonts on web site?

Tags: html, fonts, font-size

My client wants to use Arial on his pages, but he wants to make them flatter (smaller height with the same width). I could probably use font editor to flatten the font and then use font-face to display it on page, but is there easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a css-property font-stretch, but it's still not supported by any browser(has been introduced in css2).

You may use the css-property **transform** with the function `scaleY('some value smaller than 1')` , but this will scale the whole element, not only the text inside.

So I would like to say using font-face is the best solution at this time.

Comment: I was able to use transform successfully, thanks for solution. It works pretty well.